# Display all records in MySQL

Tags: mysql, perl, filter

I am trying to display all the record in  MySQL Tables.

I can do `select * from table` but this is not what i want to do.

I want to do something like this

```
select app_id, app_name from app where app_sendto = '%'
```

I've tried the above, but does not display anything.

I would like to run the above query as follows

```
$get_app = "select app_id, app_name from app where app_sendto = ?";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($get_app); 
$sth->execute('people') or die "Cannot execute sth: $DBI::errstr";
```

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: Hi @Mat thanks, Just figured out what the problem was: it should be select app_id, app_name from app where app_sendto **like** '%'

Comment: What i wanted to do was get all the applications for a particular campus. A user is only allowed to view their own campus application. for eg: Kiribati campus will have a query `$get_app = "select app_id, app_name from app where app_sendto = ?";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($get_app); 
$sth->execute('Kiribati') or die "Cannot execute sth: $DBI::errstr";` now it works fine for me, i am able to display only the applications for Kiribati campus.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Just got the solution, the query should be

```
select app_id, app_name from app where app_sendto like '%'
```